# Append write not working with google storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to append logs of android app into a file in google storage through php script which is hosted on google app engine.

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  $file_path = 'gs://s3674204-storage/logs.txt';


  if ( 0 == filesize( $file_path) || file_exists($file_path) == false ){
        $handle = fopen($file_path, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file_path);
        fwrite($handle, "Label,x,y,z".PHP_EOL);
        fclose($handle);
  }


  $final = $_POST['result'];
  $final = json_decode( $final, true );
  $label = array_keys($final);
  $coords = $final[$label[0]];

  $data = $label[0].",".$coords['x'].",".$coords['y'].",".$coords['z'];

  $myfile = file_put_contents($file_path,$data.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

 ?>
```

For first time, the file is being created but its not being able to do append write to the same file.

**file_put_contents returns false**

Code is working fine with xampp server. What's wrong with google storage?

Answer (score 1):

[Objects in Google Cloud Storage are immutable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability), meaning you cannot append to them or edit them in place. You have to fully overwrite the file with new content.